When is Abortion Allowed or considered Dharmic?
Under what circumstances would Abortion be viewed as Dharmic in scripture?

This question is similar to: Is abortion permissible if life of mother is in danger?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Bingming it is difference that's asking about a specific instance of it being dharmic and I am asking about all instances.

Well, this is because that is literally the only instance afaik in the śāstras, where abortion is actually said to be allowed. The answer that you accepted below, is actually wrong, as I stated in its comment.

This question is similar to: What is Hinduism's view on abortion?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Abortion is allowed only in the case of adultery or rape as per Yajnavalkya smriti -

If a woman subjects herself to abortion, except in the case of
pregnancy by other than her husband, and for purposes of expiation
(after rape), she becomes guilty of two great sins the murder of the
foetus and the murder of her husband.


3.72, Yajnavalkya smriti


Interesting, but why should the fetus be killed after all it isn't responsible for the action. Also is it only for the act or all forms of adultery?

@Haridasa - it probably has something to do with saving the mother's life.

Well that's not explicitly stated for health reasons.

I am interested in possible counter-views on this matter.

Can you cite the Balambhatti or Subhodini which are sub-commentaries on the Mitaksara?

@Haridasa - I think Shusruta Samhita mentions about aborting child to save a mother's life.

Indeed, but the act doesn't always lead to a mother's life being in danger biologically and also does this verse cover adultery "cheating" in general or just the act.

@Haridasa - well 'except in the case of pregnancy by other than her husband' would probably also mean adultery.

But while adultery is a crime why should the child be punished for such an action?

@Haridasa - If the fetus is dead, it may be removed. And in case the fetus is alive but cannot be safely delivered, surgical removal is forbidden for one would harm both mother and offspring. In an irredeemable situation, it is best to cause the miscarriage of the fetus, for no means must be neglected which can prevent the loss of the mother (Sushruta Samhita, Sutra 10-11).

Thank you this in regards to a mother's life.

Your verse is not found. give the link of the book along with page number

Firstly, the verse you're referring to is 1.72 not 3.72, and the translation is incorrect. This śloka doesn't sanction abortion in any case at all, like the translation. Instead, it says that a wife who does abortion, is tyājya for the husband and that it's a pāpa to do so. If a wife indulges in unchastity, she becomes śuddha by rajasrāva. However, if she gets garbhavatī as a result of this unchastity, then she is tyājya. If she does abortion, killing husband, etc. she is tyājya. If you think, I am wrong, you may very well check the commentaries such as Mitākṣarā.

@Bingming Thank you
